# Can't have access to NSDictionary in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a very strange behaviour with NSArray.

Firstly, i parsed an XML file and return a valid NSArray with NSDictionary inside:

```
NSArray *arrayOfDict = [parser parseWithXMLFile:filename];
```

In debugger it's fully valid. Then, i want to proccess all dictionaries in this array:

```
NSMutableArray* arrayOfProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary* dict in arrayOfDict) {
  Product* product = [[Product alloc] initWithName:dict[@"name"]
                                              type:dict[@"type"]
                                         imageName:dict[@"image"]
                                       description:dict[@"description"]];

  [arrayOfProducts addObject:product];
  [product release];
}
```

And in this loop is a problem: a `dict` variable has value `nil`. And i don't know what to do with this. In debugger i evaluate value of `arrayOfDict[someIndex]` and get a right value, but in the programm itself it doesn't work.

May be it's the problem with MRR, i don't feel myself confidenly while using MRR and there is a mistake of using it.

P.S. I know that using MRR is stupid today, but in this project i must use it.

Comment: By `MRR` do you mean manually allocating and releasing memory? I'm not familiar with the term. What does it stand for?

Comment: Does the program goes into for loop? If yes then what is the output of `NSLog dict` there? and what is the output of `NSLog arrayOfDict `?

Comment: @the_UB Suddenly! It works now, but of course i don't change anything in my code

Comment: Show examples of the data, check the keys carefully. MRC is manual reference counting